Is there else if statements in ternary operators?
Can I use 'else if' statement in c++ ternary operators?
I'm just still learning c++ which means I'm completely a beginner, And I'm following along with Cherno Cpp playlist in youtube.
Here's an example code of what I'm trying to do exactly.
#include <iostream>

// teranry operators

static unsigned int level = 1;
static unsigned int speed = 5;


int main() {
    speed = level < 5 ? 10 : 5;
    std::string rank = level < 10 ? "Newbie" : //rest of the code (should be an else if statement here).
    std::cin.get();
}

I have a feeling that I should just normaly type an else if statement but it would be really useful if i can actually use an ternary operator in this situation.

You can nest ternary operators and make it more difficult to read:  (a < b) ? ((c > d) ? "yes" :  "no") : (e == f) ? "apple" : "humming bird" (check the parens).  In most cases, there is nothing to be gained by using the ternary operator.  Using if statement is more readable and a good compiler at a reasonable optimization level will generate the same instructions.

Technically, there is no "else if" statement outside ternary operators, so it is a bit odd to be looking for one in them... (You can write an if statement right after the else keyword, and some people will call the result an "else if", but the language syntax does not recognize this. It's just an else clause that happens to be another if statement.)

"I'm following along with Cherno Cpp playlist in youtube...." I think a good c++ book would be better than yt tutorial videos. In particular, "c++ primer by lippman 5th edition" is the best beginner c++ book. Yt tutorials are not a good source to learn c++.

Other good sources to learn cpp from are "Learncpp.com", "cppreference.com" and "the C++ core guidelines" you may want to look those up.

Ternary operators are fun to play with. But use judiciously in code. You don't want to make the code hard to understand. Understandability (ability of others to read and quickly understand) is one of the most important qualities in good code.

There is no else if version in c++ ternary operators but you can nest them in a way that follow this format
variable = <condition 1> ? <val 1> : <condition 2> ? <val 2> : <val 3>

which is equivalent to
if (<condition 1>) {
  variable = <val 1>;
} else if (<condition 2>) {
  variable = <val 2>;
} else {
  variable = <val 3>;
}

So in your example it would look something like this
#include <iostream>

static unsigned int level = 19;
static unsigned int speed = 5;

int main()
{
    speed = level < 5 ? 10 : 5;
    std::string rank = level < 10 ? "Newbie" : 
                       level < 20 ? "Crook" :
                       level < 30 ? "Boss" : "Mafia Boss"; 
    std::cout << rank << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


You can do it, but it makes code really hard to read. If I saw it in a code review I'd get you to change it.

@John3136 I agree. It might be better to use if else instead

@JaMiT you're right. I've added line breaks to make it more readable

@John3136 - the last example is quite clear; if you're not used to it it might look tricky, but well-disciplined formatting, as in the example, makes it easy to read. And for initialization, as in the example, if... else isn't an option; you have to push the decision code into a separate function to do that, and that introduces its own set of readability issues.

@PeteBecker it's been edited since I commented. I agree it's better but I still wouldn't let it pass a review.

@John3136 -- that would require writing a separate function, and making readers of the code hunt for it instead of seeing the exact initialization in place.

@PeteBecker: There is still IIFE (with lambda), std::string rank = [&](){/*..*/}();.

@Jarod42 -- and that's more readable than a cleanly formatted conditional statement? KISS

@PeteBecker: I would probably go with function rankFromLevel which can be tested and reused ;-)
